# Query hover and click states

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, onclick, onhover

Im after some help with a layout I'm working on. Im using bootstrap to render the templates but i have a bespoke portfolio type area that I'm a little lost on.

The attached picture shows(hopefully) what I'm trying to achieve. I will have multiple blocks in rows an columns. Each block when hovered will need to show a picture with a button over the top. When the button is clicked the button state needs to change and open a panel underneath.

I need the panel to close and the block return to its original state if another block is hovered and clicked so only one panel is ever open at a time.

Now i have looked into accordions and using collapse through bootstrap but this seems a little more advanced than either of those.

Thoughts or ideas would be most appreciated on this one.

[image]

Comment: Hover shouldn't be a big deal, you can achive opening the panel via declaring a `data-target` and an ID. For more help I suggest you post some code and show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have added a fiddle here

https://jsfiddle.net/keithriches/wa6ge05p/

Comment: I can't seem to get the fiddle to operate as it should though but this essentially uses css for the hover and bootstrap picks up the wells from the in built service. I have added some js so that only one well is visible at a time

Comment: If it helps i have a dummy working in my public dropbox area at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/46091572/AE/profile-test.html